# Sql server. The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

```
begin tran
begin try
  select case when 1=0 then 0.0 else '' end --this will not work
end try
begin catch
--error has occured. But it doesnt matter. We want to continue anyway
end catch

select 1 --do something else

commit --unfortunatelly this producess error "The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file"
```

What can I do to commit transaction?
I know,   `select case when 1=0 then 0.0 else '' end` is incorrect. Thats why it is in try/catch block (in real situations this is query defined by administrator). But I want to commit the rest of operations.

Edit://
The code works as I wanted if the "Incorrect query" is for example `select 1/0`

```
begin tran
begin try
  select 1/0-- this will not work
end try
begin catch
--error has occured. But it doesnt matter. We want to continue anyway
end catch

select 1--do something else
commit --commit is done without any errors
```

Comment: one option might be to check the global `@@error` value before you commit.. `if @error != 0 begin rollback tran end else begin commit tran end`

Comment: You are attempting to deal with an antipattern I call try/squelch. There are times (albeit very rarely) where this is an ok approach but most of the time we should now about errors when they happen.

Comment: @JamieD77.
This is not solution for my problem. 
In my procedure, there are some statemenets that have to be done (in my example this is just "select 1"), and some statemenets that should be done (this is query provided by user and it can be incorrect).
If user statement is incorrect, I just log error (in catch block), and then continue to do rest of the procedure.

Comment: @Sean Lange
This is just example. In my real application there is some code in catch block (user gets error message, that query was not invoked). But in this example it is pointless to post all my code here.

Comment: HUH? How does the user get an error message from a catch block? The real problem here is that you are trying to commit only a portion of a transaction which is not how transactions work. If you really want everything to continue get rid of the transaction.

Comment: you can save the transaction before you get to the code you dont care about.. and roll back to the save point if you'd like.. then just commit what is left  http://dba-presents.com/index.php/databases/sql-server/43-nesting-transactions-and-save-transaction-command

Comment: @Jammie And thats the only solutions i can see for now. 
But there can be many user queries, and many can be incorrect. I want to try to run every user query, and return error for user, if query invocation fails.

Comment: @Sean Lange

Look at this example:

`declare  @error as varchar(max)
begin tran
begin try
  select 1/0
end try
begin catch
set  @error = 'I cant divide by zero'
end catch

exec doSomethingImportant

select 1, @error

commit`

there is error dividing 1 by 0.
In catch i just log error into variable.
Then do rest of the code
and in the end return information to user.

It generally work, but there are some cases when it doesn't

Comment: Right my point exactly. A transaction must either commit the ENTIRE transaction or rollback the entire transaction. An error will cause the transaction to be uncommittable. Are you familiar with ACID? https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/09/sql-server-acid-atomicity-consistency-isolation-durability/ A transaction by definition must be atomic. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql

Comment: @Sean Lange.
So tell my, that is difference between `select 1/0` and `select case when 1=0 then 0.0 else '' end`?
Why I can commit transaction, when in my try block is `select 1/0` and Can't  commit when in my block is  `select case when 1=0 then 0.0 else '' end`?

Comment: HUH???? Can you post that in the question instead of comments. Formatting of code in comments is just awful.

Comment: @Sean Lange
I have edited my first post.

Comment: @Włóczykijzdolinymuminków, you say that you have some transactions that should be done, and some that must be done. What you are describing is two commit blocks. By definition. You really should rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

From [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql):

"If an error generated in a TRY block causes the state of the current transaction to be invalidated, the transaction is classified as an uncommittable transaction. An error that ordinarily ends a transaction outside a TRY block causes a transaction to enter an uncommittable state when the error occurs inside a TRY block. An uncommittable transaction can only perform read operations or a ROLLBACK TRANSACTION."

From [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-transactions):

"SQL Server can tolerate some errors inside a transaction without it having to be marked as un-committable. For example SELECT 1/0 would cause an error but not force a transaction into an un-committable state."

Comment: The atomicity of transactions dictates that they should be either committed fully, or not at all. Even within try/catch, `select case when 1=0 then 0.0 else '' end` is part of the transaction.

Comment: But if i replace `select case when 1=0 then 0.0 else '' end` with `select 1/0`
it works as I wanted

Answer (score 0):

you could try checking the transaction state before you commit or exit..

```
begin tran
begin try
    select case when 1=0 then 0.0 else '' end --this will not work
end try
begin catch
--error has occured. But it doesnt matter. We want to continue anyway
end catch

select 1 --do something else

IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
    rollback tran
IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
    commit tran
```

Comment: Its not answer to my question.